# CUDA Seg Fault for Int Device to Host Copy

Tags: cuda

Why is the following simple program (24 lines) lead to segmentation fault at *shrinked_size_host* int variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>


__global__ void cuda_set(int* device_var){
   *device_var = 12;
   printf("Set device variable to: %d\n", *device_var);
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello world CPU\n");

    int* shrinked_size_device;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&shrinked_size_device, sizeof(int));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    
    cudaMemset(shrinked_size_device, 0, sizeof(int));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cuda_set<<<1,1>>>(shrinked_size_device); 
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int* shrinked_size_host = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(shrinked_size_host, shrinked_size_device, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    printf("shrinked_size_host=%d\n", *shrinked_size_host);
    return 0;
}
```

That's the output produced from the program:

1. Hello world CPU
2. Set device variable to: 12
3. Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Not sure why there is a segmentation fault.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `shrinked_size_host `

Comment: Study a CUDA sample code like vectorAdd to learn how data copying between device and host is typically done.

Comment: @talonmies, Robert Yes, that works... Thanks for the tip :)

I got confused because it was one integer instead of a list. Posted my answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out the answer to this question.

Memory for the shrinked_size_host should be allocated. So, either do:

1. *Heap allocation:* malloc or new int to allocate an integer of size 1. Remember to delete the allocated memory at the end.
2. *Stack allocation:* Use int shrinked_size_host[1];

Comment: You do not need an array of size 1. You can just use an ordinary integer and pass its address. `int shrinked_size_host;
    cudaMemcpy(&shrinked_size_host, shrinked_size_device, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`

Comment: That works even better... Thanks :)